# finite difference derivative array valued functions

Tags: python, derivative, differentiation, automatic-differentiation

Suppose I have the following code

```
import numpy as np

f = lambda x,y: (np.sum(x) + np.sum(y))**2
x = np.array([1,2,3])
y = np.array([4,5,6])

df_dx
df_dy
df2_dx2
df2_dxdy
...
```

is there a fast way to compute all the derivatives (single and mixed) of such a function? The module should perform the classical finite difference technique at the array level, ie adding `h= tol` elementwise to the array variables (depending on the derivative), computing the function and dividing by `h`.

(My real case is much more complicated as it involves an array valued function coming from a DLL I can't modify...the number of variables is arbitrary, please do not focus on this particular toy example)